# dll of project is not present in Visual Studio 2017 Modules window

Tags: visual-studio-2017

While debugging I ran into several problems using Visual Studio. I got break points not being hit because the code was being optimized behind the scenes, I disabled it. I got break points not being hit because I was using the RELEASE option on the properties of the project, I changed it to DEBUG. I got break points not being hit because the symbols weren't being loaded, all of a sudden I had to load them manually using the modules window. Now, I cannot perform the last step because one of my project doesn't appear on the modules window.

[cannot find webservices project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OOv9.png)